# Why guards are called 'guards'?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, guard-statement

Does anyone know what is the origin of the name for the construct called **guards**?

```
func x
    | cond1 -> expr1  
    ...
    | condN -> exprN
```

Wikipedia article  [Guard_(computer_science)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)) gives some historical perspective, but lacks explanation for where name came from (it just mentions that SASL was one of the first to use the name).

So far I found references to Edsger Dijkstra and his Guarded Command Language. Was he first to use the term 'guard'?

Comment: A *guard* decides who can come in, and who stays out. So the condition decides if the expression "fires".

Comment: On the close votes: the question ("Was Dijkstra the first to use the term 'guard'?") is neither broad nor opinion-based. I'm not sure whether computing history questions are on-topic or not. I'm leaning towards not, but in any case the question clearly is not about general computing hardware and software (and would probably be *even more* off-topic on SuperUser than it is here). So I squint at all of the close votes that exist so far.

Comment: not SASL, KRC .

Comment: guards are not much different from plain conditionals. and these already were in the (largely ignored) Plankalkül (although Wikipedia says it influenced Algol 58).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the term is from Dijkstra. [Guarded commands, non-determinacy and formal derivation of programs (CACM 1975)](http://spinroot.com/courses/summer/Papers/dijkstra_1975.pdf)

It's ironically hilarious that the [Wikipedia article Guard (computer science)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)) says "Guard code provides an early exit from a subroutine, and is a commonly used deviation from structured programming", lacking a fundamental appreciation of guards & structured programming, since the term became important because Dijkstra's guards were a fundamental & influential contribution to structured programming.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's pointless asking where terminology comes from. (For example why does Haskell have 'types' and 'kinds', whereas math has 'sorts'?) The wikipedia article is good.

The style of writing guards to the right does mirror maths (the wikipedia article has an example). That's probably what influenced Dijkstra. And there's the same mathematical style in Strachey 1967 'Fundamental Concepts'. (He doesn't use "guard".)

@Will Ness *guards are not much different from plain conditionals* is not right. So it's good to have a different word than "condition". Guards come after pattern-matching:

```
case x of
  (Maybe x') | x' > 0 -> ...
  Nothing {- x' not in scope here -} -> ...
```

In a case branch: first match the pattern, and that binds variables; then apply guards using the variables.

And you can extend the idea to the type level https://github.com/AntC2/ghc-proposals/blob/instance-apartness-guards/proposals/0000-instance-apartness-guards.rst

Comment: I think it's pointless to claim that someone's curiosity is pointless

Comment: `(cond ((even? 2) => (lambda (b) ...)) (else ... ;|b is not in scope here|; ...))`. potayto, potahto. :) "not much different" =/= "exactly the same". --- Looked at from sufficiently afar, everything resembles everything else. ("huh, those hadron-based objects aren't that much different from one another", says an energy-based lifeform looking at a human and a tree ...)

Comment: (BTW the @ ping does not work from the post body, only from the comments)